# How do we know that the gluon travels at $c$?

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light, standard-model, gluons

How do we know gluons travel at the speed of light?  can this be derived or is it just an assumption based on the similarity to photons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we know that gluons travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440971/)

Comment: not entirely.  As I understand it, Maxwells equations can be used to derive the speed of light, but this involves particles which react or involve electrictro-weak interactions.  Gluons react strongly, and therefore treating them as a EM reacting (ie. limited by c) particle seems to be an assumption.

Comment: The speed of light does not only  apply to photons. It applies to _all_ massless particles. Since gluons are indeed massless, it is necessary that they move with speed $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Gluons are massless in the Standard Model, and all massless particles travel at $c$. This is pretty much by definition, but a hand-wavy way to explain it is that a massless particle will be accelerated "infinitely" if given any energy at all, i.e. it will reach the maximum possible velocity $c$ instantly. Don't read too much into that hand-wavy explanation though -- the real answer is that it's the way spacetime is structured.

Comment: Neutrinos are also massless in the Standard Model. But then, according to the "massless particles travel at " principle, the observed neutrino oscillations should be impossible. So, the question of what  **evidence** exists for the massless gluon is reasonable.